# Patterns and Regular Expressions in Shell/bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

the command ls @(*xx|*AK)    in bash
what is the purpose of @ sign here and what does the | do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`, under "Pathname Expansion":

```
@(pattern-list)
    Matches one of the given patterns

a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not *regular expression*. It's Bash's *extended glob pattern*. See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) in Bash's manual for details.

By default the *extended glob pattern* support is not enabled. To enable it, run `shopt -s extglob`. For more details about the `shopt` command, see [The shopt Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).